# Scroll bar not coming on Ionic popover

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

In my `home.html` I have included `popover` page. The problem I am facing is,  have a lot of content in it and it is not showing any **scroll bar** and going out of the page.

How do I get scroll bar on the page? Below is the screenshot of my `home.html` page with `popover`.

[image]

Below is `popoverpage.html` code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row>
<!-- <ion-col size="12">
  This is example of popup
</ion-col> -->
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>

<ion-col size="12">
  <ion-button (click)="closepopup()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round" color="danger">
    Close
  </ion-button>
</ion-col>


</ion-row> 


<!--change stage starts-->
<ion-item (click)="changestage()">
  <ion-label>Change Stage</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<br>

<ion-list *ngIf="showstage == true">
  <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Lead Stage</ion-label>
    <ion-select  okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="dropdown2" >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of leadstagelist" value="{{list.name}}" checked="true">
        {{list.name}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-button (click)="change_leadstage()" expand="block"  shape="round" color="danger" *ngIf="showstage == true">
      Update Stage
</ion-button>
<!--change stage ends-->


<!--change owner starts-->
<ion-item (click)="changestage_owner()">
  <ion-label>Change Owner</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<br>

<ion-list *ngIf="showstage_o == true">
  <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Lead Owner</ion-label>
    <ion-select  okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="dropdown3">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of students" value="{{list.authId}}" checked="true">
        {{list.Name}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-button (click)="change_leadowner()" expand="block"  shape="round" color="danger" *ngIf="showstage_o == true">
      Update Owner
</ion-button>
<!--change owner ends-->


<!--Add activity starts-->
<ion-item (click)="changestage_activity()">
  <ion-label>Add Activity</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<br>

<ion-list *ngIf="addActivity_o == true">
  <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Lead Activity Note</ion-label>
    <br>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input" [(ngModel)]="val1"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-button (click)="addActivity()" expand="block"  shape="round" color="danger" *ngIf="addActivity_o == true">
      Add
</ion-button>
<!--Add activity ends-->

<!--Add follow uo starts-->
<ion-item (click)="changestage_followup()">
  <ion-label>Add Follow up</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<br>

<ion-list *ngIf="followup_o == true">
  <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Lead Followup Note</ion-label>
    <br>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input" [(ngModel)]="val2"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <br>
  <ion-item> 
    <ion-label>Lead Followup Date</ion-label>
    <br>
<!-- <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Awesome Input" [(ngModel)]="val3"></ion-input> -->

<ion-datetime value="2020-02-19" placeholder="Select Date" [(ngModel)]="val3"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" value="1990-02-19T07:43Z"></ion-datetime>

</ion-list>

<ion-button (click)="addFollowup()" expand="block"  shape="round" color="danger" *ngIf="followup_o == true">
      Add
</ion-button>
<!--Add follow up ends-->


  </ion-grid>



</ion-content>
```

Comment: user2828442, you appear to have moved onto a new question, and left this one in a confusing state. What does "doesn't work" mean in your comment on the answer from JJ Pell below? "Doesn't work" is not a helpful error report, and is liable to cause your question to be put on hold. (Moreover, it does not provide any useful clues to your helper about how they might assist you further, and it makes it necessary for your helper to ask you further questions about _how_ it does not work, which they should not have to do).

Answer (score 1):

See if adding these global css rules works

```css
  .backdrop-no-scroll ion-content {
    --overflow: hidden;
  }
  .backdrop-no-scroll ion-backdrop+* ion-content {
    --overflow: visible;
  }
```

Taken from this [thread](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16910)

Comment: copied these in global.scss but did not work